# How to open a text file from CLI using a running instance of a GTK text editor written in C?

Tags: c, gtk, gtksourceview

I have a text editor written in C using gtk+-3.x and gtksourceview3.  I would like to expand the functionality to include the ability to open a text file from the command line and add the text in this file to a new buffer in the previously opened editor.

So the question is, how do I access this text?  I can add it to a buffer,scrollwin... that isn't the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: you might try: fopen( argv[1], "r+")  then use fseek() to get to end of file, then use ftell() to determine current length of file, then use malloc to create space in your program for the file contents.  I assume the program already can keep parts of the working set of files on disk, etc. etc.

Comment: You could try explaining what part you have a problem with? communicating with an already running app or opening the file or what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your problem is what's mentioned in the title: getting an already running instance of a GTK app to do something from the command line.

[GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) and it's base class GApplication will give you the tools you need: It allows you to define actions that the new instance can invoke on the original instance (using D-Bus but that's an implementation detail). For your use case take a look at the already defined "open" action in GApplication (see [example](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/tests/gapplication-example-open.c)).

If you are using a an old version of GTK+ that doesn't have GtkApplication, you can use libunique instead -- the API is roughly the same.